# GtkTreeView Column Header Click Event

Tags: c++, linux, signals, gtkmm

I have a question. I have a `GtkListStore` and a `GtkTreeView`, and I want to sort the GtkListStore and update the result to the GtkTreeView when the user clicks on a certain column of the GtkTreeView. I am assuming that the columns are clickable, and cannot be re-ordered, so the numerical order of the columns can be used to set the sorting column's index. But I cannot seem to find which signal gets emitted when the user clicks on the header of a particular column. I have gone through the GTKMM documentation time and again, but it does not seem to be mentioned!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Gtk::TreeView::get_column(<column-no>)` to get a particular column and attach to its "clicked" signal using `Gtk::TreeViewColumn::signal_clicked()`:

```
Gtk::TreeViewColumn* col = myview.get_column(SOME_COLUMN_NUMBER);
col->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&some_method));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you're supposed to do it.

There can be several views hooked up to the same model; sorting is *not* something you do to the model, it's something you do to the view.

See the `GtkTreeSortable` interface (and its `GtkTreeModelSort` implementation).

Comment: But in this case, I do want to sort the model, because there is only one view, and the only reason the view exists is to show the user what the sorted model looks like. I can always manually sort a model like this:  `GtkListStoreName.set_sort_column_id(some_integer);` But I just cannot understand which event should trigger this.

I have no problem with sorting. I just cannot find how to detect which column header was clicked.